# how do I cast to a jquery datatable

Tags: jquery, datatable

If I don't have a reference to an existing jQuery datatable, how can i get one?  i.e. how can I cast a javascript variable to an existing datatable so I can call datatable functions upon it?

I want to do this:

```
var mytable=(dataTable)$("#mytableid");
mytable.fnGetNodes().serialize();
```

The following doesn't work:

```
var mydata= $("#mytableid").fnGetNodes().serialize();
```

presumably because jQuery doesn't realise I am operating against a datatable.
To be clear, I know the id of the table, but I don't have a reference to it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To retrieve an existing datatable, just do

```
var mytable = $('#mytableid').dataTable({"bRetrieve": true});
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct code is

```
 var mytable = $('#mytableid').dataTable();
```

That will convert your table to a datatable and allow you to use the API.

Comment: it has already been converted to a datatable by an earlier process, but I don't have access to the reference.  I therefore need to cast a var to the existing datatable, not create another one.  Thanks though.

Comment: @John The variable needs to be set to the output of the dataTable function. Is there any way that you can declare a variable and access it where you want to use the API?

Comment: No.  It is set elsewhere, and I don't have access to it, hence the casting question.